# Why Coq's `Include` is designed to instantiate functor with current interactive defining module?

Tags: coq, module

It is surprising for me to see that Coq can `Include` a functor and will instantiate it with the current interactive module.

Coq Ref Manual:

> *Command*  Include *module_type_inl* <+ *module_expr_inl**
>
> Includes the content of module(s) in the current interactive module. Here module_type_inl can be a module expression or a module type expression. **If it is a high-order module or module type expression then the system tries to instantiate module_type_inl with the current interactive module**.

A working example:

```
Module Type B.
Parameter b : Set.
End B.
Module A (ctx : B).
Definition a : ctx.b -> ctx.b := fun x => x.
End A.

Module SeeHere.
Definition b := nat.
Include A.
End SeeHere.

Print SeeHere.
(* Module SeeHere := Struct Definition b : Set.
 Definition a : b -> b.
 End *)
```

**My question is**, this behaviour seems a bit random to me -- *at least I don't find similar behaviour in OCaml's `include`* -- what is the intention/main usage for this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what the developers intended, but this feature is used in Coq's standard library to create bundled module types.  (See, e.g., [this blog post](https://www.ralfj.de/blog/2019/05/15/typeclasses-exponential-blowup.html), [this issue](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/issues/1165), [this paper](http://www.eelis.net/research/math-classes/mscs.pdf), or even [the section on packed vs unpacked records on pages 54--55 of my thesis](https://jasongross.github.io/papers/2021-JGross-PhD-EECS-Feb2021.pdf#page=54) for some discussion of the bundled and unbundled styles of records, which are sort-of like lightweight modules.)

For example, we have in [`Coq.Structures.Equalities`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.Equalities.html):

```
Module Type Typ.
  Parameter Inline(10) t : Type.
End Typ.

Module Type HasEq (Import T:Typ).
  Parameter Inline(30) eq : t -> t -> Prop.
End HasEq.

Module Type Eq := Typ <+ HasEq.
```

(Note that `Module Type A := B.` is the same as `Module Type A. Include B. End A.`)

Here we want to have both module types that are parameterized over their type (`HasEq`) and ones that have the type as a field (`Eq`).  Giving `Include` this behavior allows us to avoid duplicating definitions in the bundled and unbundled versions.